# Generate sitemap using an excel file with many urls (excel to sitemap)

Tags: python, excel, xml-sitemap

I have an excel sheet with approximately 100000 urls in it. I need to generate sitemap files which are recommended by Google. The sitemaps should be split using a grouping column.

All the rows containing "Mechanical" in a group column should be in a different sitemap and all the rows containing "Civil" should be in a different sitemap.

I am new to python and is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the excel to sitemap python package by installing it

```
pip install xl2sitemap
```

The documentation for it can be found here [Excel to Sitemap README](https://github.com/antiproblemist/excel-to-sitemap)

You will have to rename the column containing the links as **url** and the grouping column to **classifier**

Please check the excel file structure provided in the Readme file

After your excel file is formatted, you can run the following command

```
xl2sitemap example.xlsx -m 50000 -c
```

This will generate a seperate file for each group and each file will only contain a maximum of 50000 urls which is the requirement for major search engines